# Heap Size of a Node in Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra setup with 6 Node Ring single DC with RF:6 and Read:CL:1. Now at times if a particular node gets lot of requests which in turn would be passed on to all the nodes (cause of RF) it gets on to Compaction with CMS and then finally with ParNew where the whole ring gets in a hanged situation which in turn making it pretty unusable. I found that we could only solve it with increasing Heap size or tweaking in the cassandra code for only reading from the local node(as RF:6 would guarantee every node having the same data although repair etc have to be dealt separately).

How to calculate Heap Size for Cassandra node(I have two Keyspace's with total 14 CF's apart from System CF's).As per cassandra wiki this should be the heap size atleast : `memtable_throughput_in_mb * 3 * number of hot CFs + 1G + internal caches` where memtable_throughput_in_mb=128mb for my setup. The max row size for a particular CF should matter here. I am not using any row or key cache. Can someone suggest me the same.

Comment: Why are you using a replication factor of 6? I would expect the total load on your cluster to go down if you used a RF of 3 and quorum reads and writes.

Comment: Again I got the same problem on production today.We are using RF:6 with CL:1, how would RF:3 and Quorum read write make it better.At the time Would sharing the cfstats help.We have flush_largest_memtables_at: 0.75 and similar default settings.However we are not using any connectionpool for thrift with  cassandra: and I can see lot of Close_wait connections at times. Would this be the Rooot cause..

Comment: Also, what heap size are you currently running at, and how full are your heaps?  Use `nodetool info` to get those stats.